# Adding space to `echo`ed result

Tags: css

Here I have code in which `php` echoes out the number of followers, the result is displayed under Followers wrapped in `h2` tags but in the start of line i.e, under Fo, I just want to display numbers in somewhat center under followers adding several `&nbsp` to `echo mysqli_num_rows($resultfollowers);` does the work but is their any one word alternative for that rather than typing several `&nbsp`

```
<h2>Followers</h2>
<?php
$checkfollowers = "SELECT * FROM follow_user WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$resultfollowers = mysqli_query($con,$checkfollowers);
echo mysqli_num_rows($resultfollowers);
?>
```

Comment: So put the output in some HTML rather than just a simple echo!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use CSS to set a width for the container and use `text-align: center;` to center the text.

Visual presentation has nothing to do with MySQL or PHP.

Example with inline styles:

```
echo sprintf( '<p style="width: 20em; text-align:center;">%s</p>', $resultfollowers );
```